# Quicksight and Month to Date

Tags: date, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to create a control for a dashboard that allows selection of MTD. I am doing this by forcing a day of 1 and building the rest of the date, but I receive an error about adding string to a date. I have tried & and ||. Is there another way to do this?

```
ifelse(${Period}="Last_30",
addDateTime(-30,'DD',now()),
${Period}="Week",
addDateTime(-7,'DD',now()),
${Period}="Day",
addDateTime(-2,'DD',now())
${Period}="MTD",
'01/'+extract('MM',now())+"/"+extract('YYYY',now()),
${Period}="Last_Month",
'01/'+extract('MM',addDateTime(-1,'MM',now())+"/"+extract('YYYY',addDateTime(-1,'MM',now())),
now()

 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [concat](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/concat-function.html) if you want to concatenate strings. Also you have to wrap extracted date expressions in [toString](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/toString-function.html) function.

`concat('01/',toString(extract('MM',now())),"/",toString(extract('YYYY',now())))`